# Aborting Fetch Request in react native: Can't perform a react state update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So i got a famous error of can't perform a react state update. And i know that using isMounted is anti pattern and I am trying to avoid that.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.isMounted = false
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.isMounted = false
}

getWinner = async () => {
    //inside fetch
    if (this.isMounted) {
        this.setState({winner: responseJson})
    }
}
```

My question is, if i am using Fetch API (for react-native) or axios to do request. How should i unmount that in such that the error will not occur???

Note that this is refer to `fetch API` of react-native

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(API);
      this.setState({
        hits: result.data.hits,
        isLoading: false
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      });
    }
  }
```